# call lua state from every c++ file

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

I added lua into my c++ project and now I would like to know if its somehow possible to set the "L" global or something like that?

```
lua_State* L = lua_open();
```

currently I have in the main function:

```
lua_State* L = lua_open();
luaopen_base(L);
```

but on an other file I need to call this function:

```
int result = lua_tinker::call<int>(L, "Lv", 1);
```

but the "L" Doesnt work and I dont want to open & close Lua every time I have to call one function.

or should I use

```
lua_State* L = lua_open();
luaopen_base(L);
```

every time I need to call a lua function?

Comment: You will need to store `L` either globally or with singleton

Comment: Also if you need parallel execution of Lua, you should create as many lua_State*s, as many threads will work with at at one time.

Comment: @Caesar could you give an example? Im using LuaTinker https://github.com/zupet/LuaTinker